# Given N samples from a population, can you determine or approximate the probability of the N+1 sample being within a certain range?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

The question is as the title says: is it possible for me to determine the probability of the next sample ending up in a certain range?

For example, lets say I pick N grains of sand from a bucket and measure their mass, is it possible for me to determine the probability that the next grain of sand I pick from the bucket will be between 1 and 2 micrograms, or 3 and 4 micrograms?

I want to know if these are possible to determine or approximate *without* any knowledge of the true distribution of the population (grains of sand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems stupidly simple, but if you don't want to make any assumptions about the distribution, a very non-parametric method is to use the proportion of grains that were in that range in your sample. The only assumption there is that each grain of sand is independently sampled from the same distribution.

To see how this works, you can think of your experiment as a series of Bernoulli trials. Each observation is the result of a weighted coin flip, where the probability of the value lying in your desired range is $p$. So all we want to do is estimate $p$.

That means the likelihood of your sample is $P(k | p) = {N \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{(N-k)}$. It's straightforward to show that the maximum likelihood estimate of $p$ is $\hat{p} = \frac{k}{N}$. We can calculate the variance as the inverse of the Fisher information matrix (well, just value here), so $\text{Var}(\hat{p}) = \frac{p(1-p)}{N}$. The Wikipedia article on [Fisher information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Single-parameter_Bernoulli_experiment) actually derives this as an example.

Comment: What sort of error bounds does such an approximation have? Although this wasn't the answer I was looking for (what if it's a rare event? No samples currently in the N samples), it does make sense.

Comment: @Ron Updated the answer. Without doing something like imposing a prior, I don't think you'll ever be able to estimate something that never happens in your sample.

Comment: Thank you for the information! How would you impose a prior? Make an assumption given some distribution? I was thinking that if I assume the population weights are Gaussianly distributed, I can get some error in the mean and covariance, thereby giving me an approximate population distribution, and work from there.

Comment: @Ron You can definitely do that. A natural thing to do might be to assume that they fit a normal distribution (you can run some tests to test this assumption) and fit it to that. But it violates your "without any knowledge of the true distribution" stipulation.

Comment: It violates the "without any knowledge" clause, although, you have to take what you can get, right? Thanks for the answer!